# Haskell List Recursion mistake?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

Hey I am pretty new to Haskell.

So I want to eliminate all integers which are greater than 500 in a list.

```
import Data.List

leng x = if(head x > 500) then leng(tail x) else [head x]++leng(tail x)
```

I get the right output but at the end of each output is

> Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

how to fix that problem?

Comment: In general, you should use `(h:t)` instead of `[h]++t` (so here  `(head x):(leng (tail x))`). (:) is Haskell's cons function, adding a single item to the front of a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-- You need this to stop the recursion, otherwise it would try to split the list 
-- when   there are no elements left.
    leng [] = []
```

You could consider this as the stop condition for your method.

you could also rewrite your method as follow:

```
leng [] =[]
leng (x:xs) | x > 500 = leng xs
            | otherwise = x : leng xs
```

the first statement is often reocurring when working with lists in haskell. e.g.

```
last [x]    = x
-- the underscore means the value of the variable is not needed and can be ignored.
last (_:xs) = last xs
```

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
leng [] = []
```

before the current `leng x`.

But you could also do:

```
leng x = filter (<=500) x
```

and even

```
leng = filter (<=500)
```